# Laravel: Cache and authenticated users

Tags: authentication, caching, laravel, laravel-4, http-caching

I'm using the awesome [laravel-httpcache](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-httpcache) package by barryvdh to cache a page with a lot of event data on it. This works perfectly for guests and is blazing fast. However, the logged in users can mark any item on this list as favourite. These items should be highlighted in some way. Since the page is cached nothing is highlighted. Is the there a way to bypass the httpcache for logged in users? Or is it possible to cache a version of the page for each user?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the package but from looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-httpcache/tree/v0.1.1) you should be able to just add a check to the filter:

```
Route::filter('cache', function($route, $request, $response, $age=60){
    if(Auth::guest()){
        $response->setTtl($age);
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work... Once the page gets cached, the cached (= non personalized) version is delivered to the logged in users.

Comment: Well yes, that is how caching works. Once the browser get's the order to cache a specific request, it won't make it again unless the time is over or you invalidate the cache manually. A simple workaround would be to use a different URL when logged in. Also just an added GET parameter should be enough. This is often done with static resources like CSS files to "tell" the browser that the content has changed (`/css/style.css?v=1.2`)